# Vuetify Select Retaining old value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've got a Vuetify select, with the following syntax.

```
<v-select label="..." autocomplete 
     append-icon="search" :items="plots" item-value="id" item-text="plotHeader" 
     v-model="selectedPlot" v-on:change="loadPlotInformation();">
</v-select>
```

So when the page loads, the dropdown initializes with an Ajax request.  But when the user changes the value, the model reflects the old value, not the current selection.

Inside the function.

```
loadPlotInformation() {
     console.log(this.selectedPlot);
}
```

---

**Update:**

I was able to fix the issue by transitioning to blur event.  But why would change event not resolve?

Comment: You're resolving the method immediately with `loadPlotInformation()`, remove the parenthesis.

Comment: after you fixed the issue @WhyDoesMyCodeWork mentioned, try below codes: `loadPlotInformation: function(selectedItem){
      console.log(selectedItem, this.selectedPlot)
    }`

Comment: Same problem here!

Comment: @cmnardi Yeah, I tried the fixes that they commented, both didn't fix.  Blur effect rectified with a blur.

Comment: @Greg I chage to read the parameter and works for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your function to read the parameter of your function.

```
loadPlotInformation(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

But this way you need to check if you want to update your model variable

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take new value instead of the old value, you should use nextTick method.
eg:

```
   loadPlotInformation() {
     this.$nextTick(() => {
         console.log(this.selectedPlot);
        })
    };
```